# How to make googlemap to search for a particular categories

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

I'm currently working on a project which requires me using google map to search for a particular location with there categories. What i actually mean is if user search for a HOTEL for example the map should return something like

John Duran Hotel 15 miles way.

Turan Hotel 45 Miles away.

Yusad Hotel 56 Miles away.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) if you want to display a particular location (example: hotel). Check the [list of supported values](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) for the `types` property in Google Places API.

```
var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    types: ['lodging']
  };

 infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
places.nearbySearch(request, callback);
```

An example of JSON request for hotels in a 500m radius to the location could look like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=lodging&sensor=false&key=
```

Here is an [example from Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch). It allows the user to find all hotels in a given place, within a given country. It displays markers for all the hotels returned, with on-click details for each hotel.